# Incoming POST requests fail on Meteor Galaxy

Tags: meteor, mailgun, meteor-galaxy

I have been successfully receiving incoming email to a Meteor app with the use of Mailgun routes for some time, but it has now suddenly stopped working.

My setup is that I forward all emails for the domain to Mailgun where I route them to my app endpoint (through a POST request) and parse them. Mailgun offers a testing tool where I input my app endpoint URL and it’s now giving me the following response:

```
Post failed: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

The app is hosted on Galaxy and below is what my ‘incoming’ route looks like if that’s of any help.

Any ideas?

```
Picker.route('/incoming/', function(params, req, res, next) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('received successfully:\n\n');
  res.end("thanks");

  parseEmail(req.body);
});
```

Update: Switching to http didn't help..

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error (below). I had configured my callback URL to be example.com/abc but it actually should have been example.com/abc/ or example.com/abc/index.php. As a result, when Mailgun hit the URL, it was getting an HTTP 301 temporary redirect. Mailgun gave an obscure error rather than following the redirect.

Post failed: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error